# Undefined error Angular 2 class

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I don't know why I get a undefined error. This is the error message I get: "TypeError: Cannot set property 'state' of undefined"

This is my code:

```
export class MobileMenuComponent implements OnInit {

menu: any;

constructor() { 


}

ngOnInit() { 

    this.menu.state = 'inactive';

    this.menu.togglemenu = function() {

        if (this.menu.state === 'inactive'){

            this.menu.state = 'active';

        }

        else {

            this.menu.state = 'inactive';

        }

    }

}


}
```

Comment: You declared menu, but its still undefined

Comment: `menu` is set to `any`, but `any` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define this.menu as empty object in your constructor and it will work.

Comment: Thank you. Just declaring is not enough. Noted.

Answer (score 1):

`this` inside `togglemenu` function - is for function itself, it doesn't contain menu member. You should use upper `this` inside function. Like this:

```
var that = this;
this.menu.togglemenu = function() {
   if (that.menu.state === 'inactive'){
            that.menu.state = 'active';
       }
        else {
            that.menu.state = 'inactive';
        }
    }
```

Comment: This was probably going to be my next question :/ Thanks!